# Maximo BMXAA4114E - An illegal access exception occurred

Tags: maximo

I want to display a workorder with WONUM by using a request query using enterpirse maximo enterprise service. I am using SoapIU to call request with maxadmin user with all security access enabled. For external system I am using predefined EXTSYS1. I keep getting error "BMXAA4114E- An illegal access exception occurred" only with this database. I changed users enabled all security access, changed external systems and made a new object structure.

SoapIU code:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <max:QueryMXTWORKORDERCUSTOM  rsStart="0">
         <max:MXTWORKORDERCUSTOMQuery operandMode="AND">
            <!--Optional:-->
            <max:WORKORDER>
               <max:WONUM>1022</max:WONUM>
            </max:WORKORDER>
         </max:MXTWORKORDERCUSTOMQuery>
      </max:QueryMXTWORKORDERCUSTOM>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Return code:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>BMXAA4114E - An illegal access exception occurred. The associated message indicates where the exception occurred.</faultstring>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Try taking a look at the server logs corresponding to the time of the request. There is a good chance you will have additional errors in there that will hopefully let you know what is actually going on. I'm not sure this "illegal access exception" actually has anything to do with security.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It was just a random automation script that wanted another paramater for it to work.